# Time and space complexity of this particular slicing operation on lists?

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have 2 lists say nums1 with n+m elements and nums2 with m elements.
if I perform
`nums1[n-m:] = nums2`

will there be any extra space used, what is the time complexity of such operation?

Answer (score 0):

The operation you talk about is copying m elements from `num2` to `num1`.

It is not deep copy because:

```
a= [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4]]
b=[[7, 7],[8,8]]
a[2:] = b
b[0][0] = 111
```

Makes `a` equal to `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [111, 7], [8, 8]]`.

So the space used depends on the implementation of the interpreter (it could use an extra space to temporary copying).

But the optimal complexities for the operator's algorithm, not including the space for the lists themselves, are:

1. Time complexity O(m)
2. Space complexity O(1)